# Aggregate downstream test results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a jenkins workflow configuration that is running several test jobs in parallel. What I would like to do, is aggregate all test results and display them on the 'workflow' job page.
Here is my current configuration:

```
node('git && linux') {
    // dome some stuff here
}

stage "Running unit tests for $REVISION"
build job: 'unit-tests', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REVISION', value: REVISION], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REFSPEC', value: REFSPEC]]

stage "Running integration tests $REVISION"
def jobs = [:]
jobs['integration-tests-1']={build job: 'integration-tests-job-1', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REVISION', value: REVISION], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REFSPEC', value: REFSPEC]]}
jobs['integration-tests-2']={build job: 'integration-tests-job-2', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REVISION', value: REVISION], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REFSPEC', value: REFSPEC]]}
jobs['integration-tests-3']={build job: 'integration-tests-job-3', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REVISION', value: REVISION], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REFSPEC', value: REFSPEC]]}

parallel jobs

// Here I would like to add something like
// aggregateDownstream('unit-tests', 'integration-tests-1', 'integration-tests-2', 'integration-tests-3'
```

Do you know if it would be possible to achieve this?